# Php Regex exclude a certain pattern already matched

Tags: php, regex

Hi there I need a hand with the pattern below:

```
(?<=\")([0-9\.\/])+(?=\")
```

Content

```
<ul>
<li><a href="../">..</a></li>
<li><a href="1.0/">1.0/</a></li>
<li><a href="1.1/">1.1/</a></li>
<li><a href="1.23/">1.23/</a></li>
</ul>
```

The above pattern selects `../, 1.0/, 1.1/, 1.23/`

I **don't** want to match `../` but any permutation of number,period and / should match.

Give me a hand please.

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a negative lookahead assertion in your existing regex:

```
(?<=\")(?!\.\.)([0-9\.\/])+(?=\")
       ^^^^^^^^
```

[See it](http://www.rubular.com/r/yzQHAjQfrl)

Answer (score 1):

I modify your regex with adding negative lookahead ( **(?!\.)** ).

```
(?<=\")(?!\.)([0-9\.\/])+(?=\")
```